# Return a several traces plot in dash

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash

I have a basic SIR model in python for which I want to make a dash app. 
The original plot I have looks like this:

[image]

Currently I'm able to create a dash plot that looks like this:

[image]

This issue with this is that I´m able to send only onde of the plot traces, for which I use the following code in the callback method:

```
s, e, i, r,x = seir_model(h,transmission_coeff,latency_time,infectious_time,end_time,
          initial_s,initial_e,initial_i,initial_r)



return {"data":[go.Scatter(x=x,
                y=s)]}
```

How can I add the rest of the vector: e, i, r to that plot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simpy pass list of traces to "data", like this:

```
return {"data":[go.Scatter(x=x,y=s),
                go.Scatter(x=x,y=i),
                go.Scatter(x=x,y=r),
                go.Scatter(x=x,y=e)]}
```